# Stanford SemanticGraph get sentence subject

Tags: stanford-nlp

How does one get the subject of a sentence (in a general way) using the SemanticGraph component from Stanford CoreNLP?

I've tried the code posted below, but the output indicates subject is null.

```
String sentence = "Carl has 84 Skittles.";
Annotation doc = InitUtil.initStanford(sentence, "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");
SemanticGraph semGraph = doc.get(SENTENCE).get(0).get(DEPENDENCIES);
IndexedWord verb = semGraph.getFirstRoot();
IndexedWord subject = semGraph.getChildWithReln(verb, GrammaticalRelation.valueOf("nsubj"));
System.out.println(subject);
```

If I try the same code replacing the second to last line with the 3 lines below, I get the expected output of "Carl". The difference appears to be a private field of `GrammaticalRelation` called `specific`, but the value of this field appears to be sentence-specific. My question is how to get the subject in a way that can be applied to all or nearly all sentences.

```
Set<GrammaticalRelation> relations = semGraph.childRelns(verb);
GrammaticalRelation relation = relations.iterator().next();
IndexedWord subject = semGraph.getChildWithReln(verb, relation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't with the `specific` field.

`SemanticGraph.getChildWIthReln` relies on `GrammaticalRelation.equals()`, which checks if the languages of the two objects are compatible. `GrammaticalRelation.valueOf(String)` returns a `GrammaticalRelation` with language as `Language.English`, while the Stanford Parser uses `Language.UniversalEnglish`. The two languages are incompatible for some reason. Changing the call to `GrammaticalRelation.valueOf(String)` to `GrammaticalRelation.valueOf(Language, String)` solved the problem.